# Create and download PDF based on JSON sent by AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I'm trying to create a PDF file using iText based on JSON from a client. HTML form data doesn't suit me because it encodes JSON and it does not work properly in some browsers, so i tried to use AJAX instead. But after all i got an empty PDF file.

I tried to use the following:

```
            that.parsedEstimator = JSON.stringify(json); //target object
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<SERVLET_PATH>",
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                data: that.parsedEstimator,
                success: function (data) {
                    a = document.createElement('a');
                    var binaryData = [];
                    binaryData.push(data);
                    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/pdf"}));
                    a.download = "Estimation.pdf";
                    a.style.display = 'none';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            });
```

There's a response processing from the servlet

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Estimation.pdf");
```

What should i do to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is the output of console.log(data)

Comment: @SrinivasanSekar 
https://ibb.co/yBTqZGX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting `responseType` to `blob` does the trick , add  `xhrFields: {responseType: "blob"}` to your existing code,

```
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<SERVLET_PATH>",
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                data: that.parsedEstimator,
                xhrFields: {responseType: "blob"},
                success: function (data) {
                    a = document.createElement('a');
                    var binaryData = [];
                    binaryData.push(data);
                    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/pdf"}));
                    a.download = "Estimation.pdf";
                    a.style.display = 'none';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately it leads to the following exception


     "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'blob')."

Comment: where you are using responseText ??

Comment: i dont see responseText in your code @EugeneMacsyom it is tested code i tested downloaded the file. Please use the same code or show me the code you're using

Comment: This is a jQuery issue:

https://ibb.co/DWz9gXw
https://ibb.co/SmQWkJ5

I used the code you've provided.

Comment: mine jquery 3.4. urs?? can you upgrade ?

Comment: i have jQuery JavaScript Library v1.12.4-aem.

Comment: Thanks for your support! I managed to solve this issue with native AJAX using response instead of responseText.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193677/discussion-between-srinivasan-sekar-and-eugene-macsyom).